# ORA-00936: missing expression while running subquery in AVG()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I've got three tables, **Accounts**, **Clients** and **Ops**, which represent clients having some bank accounts and some operations (withdraw/deposit) into those bank accounts.

The withdraw/deposit info is decided based on the amount stored in the `ops.value` field (either negative or positive).

Now, if I want to compute the average value of the maximum positive operations made by people with an age < 25 and people with an age > 40: I thought about filtering first those people. This means, selecting only people with these age ranges, which have operations = maximum value stored in `ops.value`. Then, computing the `AVG()` of it.

This is the query I thought of:

```
SELECT AVG(
    SELECT ops.value FROM ops
    JOIN accounts
    ON accounts.cid = ops.cid
    JOIN clients
    ON clients.ssn = accounts.ssn
    WHERE ops.value = (
        SELECT MAX(ops.value) FROM ops 
    )
    AND clients.age < 25
    OR clients.age > 40
) FROM ops
```

The problem is, I get the following error:

```
Error at line 2/5: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I don't think I need to mention more of the table structure, because the problem only lays in the `SELECT AVG (...)` part. Only writing the query inside the `AVG()` function will result in a proper entity set, but putting everything under `AVG()` seems to ruin my query.

What may be the problem, in this case?

Comment: You are missing parentheses. A subquery consists of a query surrounded by parentheses, so with the parentheses that belong to the `AVG` you'll have something like `AVG( (select ...) )`.

Comment: Apart from that, your query doesn't seem to make any sense. The subquery is not correlated to the main query, i.e. you can run it stand-alone. It selects the maximum value in the ops table as often as there is an age match. Then you take the average, which again is the maximum ops value (or null, if no row matches the age range). You get this same result for every ops row. So, a result could look like this: 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 or this: null, null, null, null, null, null. I don't think this is what you are after.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right with both my query syntax error and with the average thing that always returns the maximum value. Didn't think about it this far. Maybe I misinterpreted the requirement. Thank you!

Comment: On a side note: Make sure you get the query ready quick and run it today. Tomorrow some clients may already have become 25 or 41 and their stored ages become stale ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial error is because `avg()` expects an expression, which you can achieve by converting your subquery to an expression, by enclosing that in another layer of parentheses:

```
SELECT AVG(
  (
    SELECT ops.value FROM ops
    ...
    OR clients.age > 40
  )
) FROM ops
```

but that will get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" because you'll get more rows than you expect; which is because your logic is ambiguous and needs extra parentheses:

```
SELECT AVG(
  (
    SELECT ops.value FROM ops
    WHERE ops.value = (
        SELECT MAX(ops.value) FROM ops 
    )
    AND (clients.age < 25
    OR clients.age > 40)
  )
) FROM ops
```

That will return a single value, but that is just the maximum value, because you aren't correlating to get the maximum *per client*. (And it will still get too-many-rows if multiple clients have the same maximum value.) And averaging a single value isn't useful.

Adding correlation isn't as simple as it looks as you need to correlate at client level.

But you don't need to do that really; you can get the maximum value for each client with:

```
select c.ssn, max(o.value)
from clients c
join accounts a on a.ssn = c.ssn
join ops o on o.cid = a.cid
where c.age < 25 or c.age > 40
group by c.ssn
```

and then use that as a subquery - CTE or inline view - to get the average:

```
select avg(max_value) as result
from (
  select c.ssn, max(o.value) as max_value
  from clients c
  join accounts a on a.ssn = c.ssn
  join ops o on o.cid = a.cid
  where c.age < 25 or c.age > 40
  group by c.ssn
)
```

(You don't actually need the `c.ssn` in the subquery's select list, but I've left it in for clarity.)

Or you can nest the aggregation, and just do:

```
select avg(max(o.value)) as result
from clients c
join accounts a on a.ssn = c.ssn
join ops o on o.cid = a.cid
where c.age < 25 or c.age > 40
group by c.ssn
```

but the compactness can make it harder to follow what's happening, so you might prefer the more verbose version, as @ThorstenKettner suggested in a comment.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x_0RzKdU)

Comment: I must admit I don't like Oracle's nested aggregation functions (`AVG(MAX(o.value))`). I must always look twice to understand that such queries result in one row despite the group by clause. I still prefer the non-propriatary `select avg(max_value) from (select max(o.value) as max_value from ...)`, even though it's more wordy.